# Prevent button press without login

Tags: php

How do I Grey out a input button without the user being logged on?

If a user is logged in this script is run

```
echo $name.':' . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
```

So obviously is the user is not logged in I either get errors or $name isn't printed on the page.

Edit: This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" onclick="
if ($_SESSION['sess_user']){

}else{
this.disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. We are going to need some more code and explanation to help you out here. There are a bunch of variables in your snippet that seem to appear out of nowhere, and you talk about an input, but there is no input in your code... Please post al the relevant code!

Comment: First off, you don't need to concatenate a string to a string to a string.  But can you be clearer about your question?  What input are you referring to?  What have you tried?

Comment: @chandlermania I've put some code in my edit but it doesn't work since I don't really know what i'm doing... 
I basically want the input button to be greyed out or unavailable unless the user is logged in

Comment: Start with basic HTML (no PHP for now). Can you disable the button with just the markup? That will tell you what you need to get to. From there, work backwards - what will I need to do in PHP to achieve that result?

Comment: You should still validate on server-side too. Users can use development tools to re-enable a button on the client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
 <?php

        $disabledString = "";
        if ($_SESSION['sess_user']){
            $disabledString = "";
        }else{
            $disabledString = 'disabled="disabled"';
        }

    ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" <?= $disabledString ?> />
```

This will either print (button disable) in browser:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" disabled="disabled" />
```

Or (not enabled):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" />
```

Comment: Just what I need, thanks very much for taking the time to help me.
Only thing I changed was ($_SESSION['sess_user']) to (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))